# AJAX no output after evaluation through if-statements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, echo

So I've got this file index.php that gives a form to upload an image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Unnamed</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Include styles -->
        <link href = "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Include jQuery -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Include form plugin -->
        <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
        <!-- Javascript --> 
        <script> 
            // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
                $('#insert_movie').ajaxForm(function() { 
                    $('#message').load('upload_file.php'); 
                }); 
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Message banner -->
        <div id='message'></div>

        <!-- Insert a movie into the database -->
        <h1>Add a new movie to the list</h1>
        <form id="insert_movie" action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: it might not be familiar to you guys, but I've used a plug-in for jQuery in order to do easy AJAX-ing.
You might want to check this [link](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

I evaluate this form via upload_file.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Upload the image
$allow = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

$todir = 'images/';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) // is the file uploaded yet?
    {
        $info = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['file']['name']) ); // whats the extension of the file

        if ( in_array( end($info), $allow) ) // is this file allowed
        {
            if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir . basename($_FILES['file']['name'] ) ) )
            {
                echo "Great";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // error this file ext is not allowed
            echo 'Choose another file extension';
        }
    }
}
 echo "this works";

?>
```

So the problem is that nothing beside "this works" is ever rendered in the  tags. However the upload was performed perfectly.

All help is appreciated!

EDIT: so when I just forget the ajaxing and simply get redirected to upload_file.php, everything gets rendered perfectly fine...

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: why are you doing !! on this line `if ( !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] )`

Comment: Actually, those are perfectly valid @mamdouhalramadan Call it a PHP quirk ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I know, but it is just weird!! !! !!

Comment: I thought so too at first. I learned that one today actually. @mamdouhalramadan Try this `$t = true; if(!! $t){ echo "true";}`

Comment: I think the problem is here:
`$info = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['file']['name']) );`. Should be `$info = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) );`

Comment: having !! is the same as saying it is not dissimilar instead of it's like.. :) @Fred-ii-

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan it explicitly converts operand to `boolean`. it is the same as: `if ( (bool)$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] )`

Comment: I guess two negatives make a right; just like multiplying two negative numbers I guess. @mamdouhalramadan which will equal a positive. Math is indeed a strange animal on it own.

Comment: @hindmost - I already Know that, but I'm just saying it is weird :)

Comment: yeah it is a bit odd indeed, so I just changed it however there used to be a reason for that to be used in a previous prototype, but I can't seem to remember what that was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your form is send via ajaxForm to  upload_file.php and everything should work fine in this call returning the expected string. With this server response your callback function is called and here you call upload_file.php again without any parameters and render the result in the div, that is only "this works" . You should use the plugin like the following:

```
$('#insert_movie').ajaxForm({
      success: function(response) { 
           $('#message').html(response); 
      }});
```

Comment: i've tried to take this over litteraly but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Response is the text returned by the server, when it receives the ajax form. Look at this fiddle to see basic working http://jsfiddle.net/EkKxF/14/ but I am sure the problem is your js code. Try to use the developer tools in chrome to see what actually happens on submit. What request is send and what does it return. I am pretty sure your code produces two requests to upload_file.php, and the first should contain the right result.

Comment: wow thanks, this solved it entirely! Thanks a lot!!! Another thing I've learnt today

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't need use !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] better write this

```
if ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
```

But better you should learn how to debug your code, that's the easiest way:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
var_dump($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if ( !!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) // is the file uploaded yet?
{
    $info = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['file']['name']) ); // whats the extension of the file
    var_dump($info);
    if ( in_array( end($info), $allow) ) // is this file allowed
    {
        var_dump($todir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']));
        if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir . basename($_FILES['file']['name'] ) ) )
        {
            echo "Great";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // error this file ext is not allowed
        echo 'Choose another file extension';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: well that's just the problem, I can't use any var_dump inside the if-statement, since it just isn't performed